# Weird AttributeError: OpenMDAO says param has not been initialized when I run my simulation under mpirun

Tags: mpi, openmdao

I am running [developmental scientific code](https://github.com/WISDEM/FLORISSE/blob/develop/test/exampleOptimizationAEP.py). I am stuck on a cryptic error message, and am curious what the OpenMDAO team thinks. When I run the code in serial, it works with no issues. When I run it under `mpirun`, OpenMDAO throws a cryptic error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test/exampleOptimizationAEP.py", line 129, in <module>
    prob['ratedPower'] = ratedPower
   .....
   File "/scratch/jquick/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao-1.7.3-py2.7.egg/openmdao/core/vec_wrapper.py", line 1316, in __setitem__
    (self.name, name))
AttributeError: 'params' has not been initialized, setup() must be called before 'ratedPower' can be accessed
```

I am not sure how to approach this. There is nothing obviously different about the `ratedPower` variable in the code. What information does this error give me about what is going wrong?

Comment: can you come up with a self-contained simple example that exhibits this problem?

Comment: What are you willing to call self-contained? The software I link to is open source. It requires the Akima package https://github.com/WISDEM/Akima. I'm not sure if we can create a simpler reproducible example.

Comment: by self contained, I meant a simple (single file) test case with toy components. I believe this is a bug in the framework, and i was refering to something that could conceivably be added to the openmdao test suite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in OpenMDAO <= v1.7.2. Look at the output of check_setup and see the list of `parameters without associated unknowns`. You will find that variable in there. When running in parallel (because of the bug), you can not set any hanging params (ones without associated unknowns) in your setup script.

The way to fix it is to add an IndepVarComp to any variable you need to initialize the value of.

Comment: Check out the script I linked to. It happens after I call `setup()`

Comment: `prob.setup(check=False)` ... run it with check=True. Something is likely erroring in the setup and you're not seeing it. Perhaps you're not getting the right impl, or there is some other issue

Comment: It seems like a clue that it only fails under `mpirun`. I'm sure this is cause by an error deep within our `FLORISSE` model. Searching for this error has been challenging, and we wanted to see if there's any information we can tease out about this issue based on the error. You might be right that different processors are out-of-order, causing this issue. I tried `prob.setup(check=True)`. I also tried adding `MPI.COMM_WORLD.Barrier()` after the `prob.setup(check=False)` line. Neither of these attempts affected the error message.

Comment: when you run with check=False, is `ratedPower` listed as having no associated unknown? and what version of OpenMDAO are you running?

Comment: Yes, that is what we are seeing. How can we get rid of having no associated unknown? We are confused why this works in serial not parallel. We are running `1.7.3`.

Comment: ok. I know whats going on here. This is a bug. You can fix it by adding IndepVarComps for anything you need to set that doesn't currently have an unknown.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129620/discussion-between-justin-gray-and-kilojoules).